# What is the difference between <ogc:Literal>wms_scale_denominator</ogc:Literal> and MaxScaleDenominator/MinScaleDenominator

Tags: sld, zoom

I take my first steps in creating SLDs using the documentation.

For [TextSymbolizer](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/reference/textsymbolizer.html)
I found this code snippet to achieve different views in different zoom levels - Zoom-based views.

```
   <CssParameter name="font-size">
     <ogc:Function name="Categorize">
       <ogc:Function name="env">
         <ogc:Literal>wms_scale_denominator</ogc:Literal>
       </ogc:Function>
       <ogc:Literal>12</ogc:Literal>
       <ogc:Literal>300</ogc:Literal>
       <ogc:Literal>10</ogc:Literal>
       <ogc:Literal>2500</ogc:Literal>
       <ogc:Literal>8</ogc:Literal>
     </ogc:Function>
   </CssParameter>
```

For [PointSymbolizer](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/cookbook/points.html#zoom-based-point)
I found this code snipped to achieve different views in different zoom levels - Zoom-based views.

```
 <FeatureTypeStyle>
     <Rule>
       <Name>Large</Name>
       <MaxScaleDenominator>160000000</MaxScaleDenominator>
       <PointSymbolizer>
         <Graphic>
           <Mark>
             <WellKnownName>circle</WellKnownName>
             <Fill>
               <CssParameter name="fill">#CC3300</CssParameter>
             </Fill>
           </Mark>
           <Size>12</Size>
         </Graphic>
       </PointSymbolizer>
     </Rule>
     <Rule>
       <Name>Medium</Name>
       <MinScaleDenominator>160000000</MinScaleDenominator>
       <MaxScaleDenominator>320000000</MaxScaleDenominator>
       <PointSymbolizer>
         <Graphic>
           <Mark>
             <WellKnownName>circle</WellKnownName>
             <Fill>
               <CssParameter name="fill">#CC3300</CssParameter>
             </Fill>
           </Mark>
           <Size>8</Size>
         </Graphic>
       </PointSymbolizer>
     </Rule>
     <Rule>
       <Name>Small</Name>
       <MinScaleDenominator>320000000</MinScaleDenominator>
       <PointSymbolizer>
         <Graphic>
           <Mark>
             <WellKnownName>circle</WellKnownName>
             <Fill>
               <CssParameter name="fill">#CC3300</CssParameter>
             </Fill>
           </Mark>
           <Size>4</Size>
         </Graphic>
       </PointSymbolizer>
     </Rule>
   </FeatureTypeStyle>
```

So I wonder why there is a different syntax and what is the difference between `<ogc:Literal>wms_scale_denominator</ogc:Literal>` and `MaxScaleDenominator/MinScaleDenominator`

Answer (score 2):

`<MinScaleDenominator>160000000</MinScaleDenominator>` and `<MaxScaleDenominator>320000000</MaxScaleDenominator>` specify a start and end scale to display the content of the containing `<Rule>` at. While `<ogc:Literal>wms_scale_denominator</ogc:Literal>` is a variable name being passed to the `env` function, which will return the current scale denominator.

So in:

```
<CssParameter name="font-size">
     <ogc:Function name="Categorize">
       <ogc:Function name="env">
         <ogc:Literal>wms_scale_denominator</ogc:Literal>
       </ogc:Function>
       <ogc:Literal>12</ogc:Literal>
       <ogc:Literal>300</ogc:Literal>
       <ogc:Literal>10</ogc:Literal>
       <ogc:Literal>2500</ogc:Literal>
       <ogc:Literal>8</ogc:Literal>
     </ogc:Function>
   </CssParameter>
```

You extract the current scale denominator (`env`) and use it for a look up in the `Categorize` function so that below 300 the font size is 12pt, between 300-2499 it is 10pt and above 2500 it is 8pt.

Comment: Thank you @Ian Turton